# EditText выставить под RecyclerView при появлении клавиатуры

Tags: android, recyclerview

Не могу заставить двигаться RecyclerView вверх при появлении клавиатуры при этом чтобы список был на весь экран если в нем мало элементов(чтобы клавиатура была под списком при появлении клавиатуры). Сейчас при появлении клавиатуры и EditTexta, EditText нахдится поверх RecyclerView. Как иметь RecyclerView на весь экран но при этом если показывается EditText и клавиатура RecyclerView был выше клавиатуры и EditTexta

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/editText1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/recyclerView"
        android:hint="@string/add_item"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/container"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:saveEnabled="true"
        android:inputType="text" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
```

Manifest.xml

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:label="test">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

Данная проблема решается простым добавлением в манифест строки:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Эту строку нужно добавить в активность в которой находится ваш список. [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16411056/how-to-adjust-layout-when-soft-keyboard-appears) похожий вопрос.

Comment: У меня одно активики, и я  добавил это в Manifest в activity, все так же, даже добавил это и в application и в activity, не помогает, клавиатура все так же появляется поверх списка

Comment: а зачем у вас в разметке два `<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout`?

Comment: Пытался эксперементировать, но я уже убрал его, это не помогает тоже

Comment: Вы можете попробовать скопировать код и запустить у меня не работает, EditText то прячется под RecyclerView но RecyclerView на весь экран. Есть вариант с fillparent но она depricated

Comment: вероятнее всего проблема в разметке, попробуйте переделать все на relative layout. В ответе рабочий способ, проблемой может быть разметка которая не хочет подгонять свои размеры под новый элемент экрана.

Comment: да, проблема в разметке, вот что именно не хочет подгонять свои размеры не могу понять

Comment: Может ли как то android:layout_height="match_parent" RececyclerView влиять?

Comment: попробуйте заменить на `wrap_content` или `fill_parent`

Comment: С RelativeLayout ни с LinearLayout с соответсвующими изменения и разынми вариантам не помогло

Comment: wrap_content не подходит потому что список будет не на весь экран. А fill_parent depricated и к тому же с ним тоже не помогло

Comment: вы пробовали wrap content?

Comment: пробовал, если там много значений, EditText так же появляется над RecyclerView

Comment: Честно говоря это не решает проблему, в ответе обновленная разметка, могли бы ли вы попробовать с ним поиграться и вы увидите что это не помогает

Answer (score 0):

Придется прокручивать лист программного, для этого использовать scrollToPosition

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(myListData.size - 1)
```

К сожалению

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

не работает с RecyclerView как ожидается/хочется.

А если еще динамически появлется и исчезает EditText и его нужно отображать под RecyclerView нужно программно добавлять и убирать marginBottom EditTexta

```
        recyclerView.layoutParams = (recyclerView.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams).apply {
            bottomMargin = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.edit_text_size)
}
```

В случае если editText показывается по действия какой либо кнопки можно использовать

```
editText.height
```

вместо

```
 resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.edit_text_size)
```

так как UI уже отрисован и размер известен во время изменения marginBottom

Если editText начинает показывать сразу при открытии активити, размер можно добавить в resource и использовать общее значение либо брать размер после отрисовки UI